# smart hightlight function for php

Tags: php

I need help with writing a function for smart selection of fragments in the text.

Src text = "Regulation is mediated via many different mechanisms"

HightLight string = "mediate via"

Expected Result = "Regulation is **mediated via** many different mechanisms"

I found one solution in google, but it is not work correctly with strings with dynamic endings

```
<?php
 
$string = "The monkey hangs from the door";
$keyword = "the";
 
function highlightkeyword($str, $search) {

    $occurrences = substr_count(strtolower($str), strtolower($search));
    $newstring = $str;
    $match = array();
 
    for ($i=0;$i<$occurrences;$i++) {
        $match[$i] = stripos($str, $search, $i);
        $match[$i] = substr($str, $match[$i], strlen($search));
        $newstring = str_replace($match[$i], '[#]'.$match[$i].'[@]', strip_tags($newstring));
    }
 
    $newstring = str_replace('[#]', '<b>', $newstring);
    $newstring = str_replace('[@]', '</b>', $newstring);
    return $newstring;
 
}
 
?>
```

Another examples:

Ex1:

src = is mediated via many

search = mediate via

result = is [b]mediated via[/b] many

Ex2:

src = are meddling in local affairs.

search = meddle in

result = are [b]meddling in[/b] local affairs.

Ex3:

src = who can not get married in France.

search = marry in

result = who can not get [b]married in[/b] France.

!! search string contain **marry** in, but source contain **married** in

Comment: It's working fine as the code generates: `<b>The</b> monkey hangs from <b>the</b> door` ... what is it doing for you?

Comment: You want it to guess when you say "mediate via" to know you meant "mediated via"? Because your string "Regulation is mediated via many different mechanisms" does not contain "mediate via"

Comment: I recommend using the `strong` tag over `b` tag.

Comment: Yes, you are all right! The main problem is highlight phrase with dynamic endings. 

Ex: 

src = is mediated via many

search = mediate via

result = is [b]mediated via[/b] many

Ex2: 

src = are meddling in local affairs.

search = meddle in

result = are [b]meddling in[/b] local affairs.

Ex3: 
src = who can not get married in France.

search = marry in

result = who can not get [b]married in[/b] France.


!! search string contain <b>marry</b> in, but source contain <b>married</b> in

Comment: Please share more details about your attempts. Also, why not use this as an exercise to learn some test-driven development?

Answer (score 1):

To make patterns recognizable you can use the power of regex

```php
function highlightkeyword($keyword, $string) {
    return preg_replace("/{$keyword}/", '<strong>\\0</strong>', $string);
}
```

### Examples

```
$string = "Regulation is mediated via many different mechanisms";
$keyword = "mediate.*? via";
echo highlightkeyword($keyword, $string), PHP_EOL;
```

`Regulation is <strong>mediated via</strong> many different mechanisms`

---

```
$string = "Who can not get married in France.";
$keyword = "marr(ied|y)";
echo highlightkeyword($keyword, $string), PHP_EOL;
```

`Who can not get <strong>married</strong> in France.`

---

```
$string = "Who can not marry in France.";
$keyword = "marr(ied|y)";
echo highlightkeyword($keyword, $string), PHP_EOL;
```

`Who can not <strong>marry</strong> in France.`

Comment: The keywords could be endlessly expanded. Different lexical localities (color versus colour) will also factor into play here but the power shown with `preg_replace` is hopefully evident.

Comment: Maybe the usage of language powered search engines like ElasticSearch would make sense. It is capable of singular/plural cases and typos.

Comment: Now you'll get to answer more questions about how to use ElasticSearch too